# ajax return variable inside .prepend()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a select box that I would like to add to a string inside my .prepend(). I can't hard code the select box and its options as they change. To overcome this, I am using an ajax call to assemble the select box and its option values in a php script then sending it back then trying to use this return variable as the HTML that needs to concat to the hard coded HTML inside my prepend. Gah! This is proving difficult, probably a simple syntax error but I can't seem to find a solution.

I have tried using PHP's htmlspecialchars on a test version. When this comes back and i try to use to to concat, it doesn't work, however if i just hard-code the same thing it does.

I guess what i need is a block of code, which is generating with while loops on the PHP side to translate into readable HTML that I can concat to my hard-coded HTML inside .prepend(). Not confusing right?

Here is where I would append

```
$(combidID).prepend('ajax return variable');
```

PHP select box assembly that needs to come back and be captured in a variable.

```
  echo "<select class='typenew' style='margin-top:13px;'><option id='$selID'>$sel</option>";
$ports_s = "SELECT * FROM FF_Account_Types ORDER BY account_type";
$ports_q = mysql_query($ports_s);
while($ports_f = mysql_fetch_array($ports_q)){
echo "<option value='$ports_f[account_type_id]'>$ports_f[account_type]</option>";
} echo "</select>";
```

Any help would be wonderful. Thank you

Comment: Please avoid using `mysql_*` functions as the library is deprecated. Please use either `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: I think your backend (php) should return json to the frontend, but not parts of html

Comment: Praveen, Thank you. I starting learning PHP out of a book, and go figure it was outdated so everything was mysql... I plan to go back and update my code to to mysqli. However when i try to do it nothing works. Do you know how to fix this, command line I'm guessing. Iv only been at this half a year, so I'm still ironing out the kinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is with your echo statement. While dealing with the ajax request you must try to echo data only once.
Hence to solve your problem try to create a string from your data using the while loop 
after the looping finished echo the string as it is. Then you will get the complete select box html

```
$outputStr =  "<select class='typenew' style='margin-top:13px;'><option id='$selID'>$sel</option>";
$ports_s = "SELECT * FROM FF_Account_Types ORDER BY account_type";
$ports_q = mysql_query($ports_s);
while($ports_f = mysql_fetch_array($ports_q)){
$outputStr .= "<option value='$ports_f[account_type_id]'>$ports_f[account_type]</option>";
} $outputStr .=  "</select>";
echo $outputStr
```

I hope this will work

Comment: Intelligent solution. While this consolidates the box, its still not functional. Oddest thing. I took your solution and made it echo inside htmlspecialchars, echoed it into a div on my page, copied this html string then used this string inside the prepend and it works lol. For some reason it doesn't like the variable version??? What the heck am I missing here???

Comment: Be sure to check your $outputStr value ... whether the php variables are correctly appended in the string or not

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your solution as it is correct. I was trying to perform the prepend outside of my ajax brackets, hence it wasn't recognizing the variable. Moved it inside and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a PHP variable:

```
echo "<option value='$ports_f[account_type_id]'>$ports_f[account_type]</option>";
```

You need to enclose them inside the `{}`. So please make it this way:

```
echo "<option value='{$ports_f[account_type_id]}'>{$ports_f[account_type]}</option>";
```

> **Note 1:** Please avoid using `mysql_*` functions as the library is deprecated. Please use either `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.
>
> **Note 2:** Please make sure you output only PHP code, or data, and do not output any HTML, in order to preserve the separation between presentation and logic.